# Oracle: What is the best way to use two tables in a mutually exclusive way?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following sample query

```
select a.name,c.company
from employee a, company c 
where a.comp_id = c.comp_id
and a.active='Y'
```

Now I have two new tables

**company_profile**, (Profile values for each company. Each company may or may not have data in this table)

**profile_defaults**  (contains default profile values for each profile item  independent of company)

Now I need to refer to column "**show_data**" in **company_profile** for a specific company. If there is no row for that company then i need to take the value from the **profile_defaults** table. How do I integrate this logic in the first query which I mentioned above in the best possible way.

Table

---

**Employee**

|Name|Comp_id|active|

**Company**

|Comp_id|Name|

**Company_Profile**

|comp_profile_id|profile_id|comp_id|profile_name|profile_value|

**Profile_Defaults**

|profile_id|profile_name|profile_value|

There are many other tables used. But I shortened it for four tables alone for this case now.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` both new tables and use `COALESCE()` (or `NVL()`) if you prefer Oracle-specific).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT a.name, c.company, NVL(cp.profile_value, pd.profile_value)
FROM employee a INNER JOIN company c
ON a.comp_id = c.comp_id
LEFT JOIN company_profile cp
ON c.comp_id = cp.comp_id
LEFT JOIN profile_defaults pd
ON cp.profile_id = pd.profile_id
```

This solution assumes that you have columns `comp_id` in both the `company_profile` and default `profile_defaults` tables to which you can join a record for a given company.  As @PM77-1 mentioned, I use `NVL()` to first check the `company_profile` table, and default to `profile_defaults` if nothing is found in the former.

Comment: Just to clarify Tim. The value of company id will not be available as part of `profile_defaults` table. I have to use a different column called `profile_id` to get the exact value from `company_profile` if it has the company value or I must make use of default value from `profile_defaults` table

Comment: What is the column in `profile_defaults`to which you would be joining a given record from a company?

Comment: Have added the sample table schema in question. If it is `company_profile` I need to check for `comp_id` and a specific `profile_id`. If it is `profile_defaults` I need to check only for `profile_id`.